# Am I evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{1/x}$ correctly?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{1/x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(\ln x)'}{(x^{-1})'}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} -x=0$$

**Am I correct?**

*But here's the thing, what's the difference between $x\to 0^+$, $x \to 0^-$, or $x\to 0$. They all are the same in this case.*

Comment: Note to establish this limit, it is enough to know $\;\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln x}x=0$, which is basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your evaluation.

No you are not correct about $x\to 0^+, x \to 0^-, x \to 0$ all being the same in this case.

$x \to 0^+$ means we are taking the limit as $x$ goes to $0$, but restricting our attention to values of $x > 0$ only. We don't care what it does below $0$

$x \to 0^-$ means we are taking the limit as $x$ goes to $0$, but restricting our attention to values of $x < 0$ only. We don't care what it does above $0$.

$x \to 0$ means we are taking the limit as $x$ goes to $0$ on both sides.

In this case, only $x \to 0^+$ is possible. because $\ln x$ is not defined for $x < 0$.